# Maximizing a weighted sum of logarithms

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, logarithms, convex-optimization

I'm trying to show that for:

$$p^* \equiv \max_{x} \sum^{k=n}_{k=1} a_k \ln x_k
$$

Where:

$
x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
x \geq 0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} x_k=c \\
c > 0 \\
\forall a_k, a_k > 0 \\
a \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} a_k
$

That:

$$
p^* = a\ln{\frac{c}{a}}+\sum^{k=n}_{k=1} a_k \ln a_k
$$

I'm really not certain where even to begin with this derivation.

Comment: Try the KKT approach.

Comment: @LinAlg what's a good resource for KKT? I'm not super familiar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Answer (score 2):

With the Lagrange multiplier method you want to maximize $p(x)=\sum a_k ln(x_k) +\lambda (c-\sum x_k)$.

Differentiating w.r.t. the $x$'s and setting equal to zero gives $\frac{a_k}{x_k}=\lambda$.

Imposing the constraint $c=\sum x_k=\frac{\sum a_k}{\lambda}=\frac{a}{\lambda}$. It follows that $\lambda=a/c$.

So $x_k=\frac{a_k }{ \lambda}=\frac{c a_k}{a}$.

So $p^*=\sum a_k ln(x_k)=\sum a_k ln(\frac{c a_k}{a})=\sum a_k (ln(\frac{c}{a}) + ln(a_k))=aln(\frac{c}{a})+\sum a_k ln(a_k)$

Comment: why is there not an aditional term for the constraint $x\ge 0$? i.e. $p(x) = \sum a_k ln(x_k) +\lambda(c-\sum x_k) -\sum \lambda_i x_i$?

Answer (score 1):

I shall come back with a Lagrangian approach tomorrow.  However, I now present a solution using the [Weighted AM-GM Inequality](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality#Weighted_Form).

We have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{a_k}{a}\,\left(\frac{a\,x_k}{a_k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\,x_k=c\,,$$
with 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{a_i}{a}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\,a_k}{a}=\frac{a}{a}=1\,.$$
By the Weighted AM-GM Inequality, we have
$$c=\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{a_k}{a}\,\left(\frac{a\,x_k}{a_k}\right)\geq \prod_{k=1}^n\,\left(\frac{a\,x_k}{a_k}\right)^{\frac{a_k}{a}}\,.$$
Take logarithm on both sides of the inequality above, we get
$$\ln(c)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{a_k}{a}\,\ln\left(\frac{a\,x_k}{a_k}\right)=\frac{1}{a}\,\sum_{k=1}^n\,\Big(a_k\,\ln\left(x_k\right)-a_k\,\ln\left(a_k\right)+a_k\,\ln(a)\Big)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\,\ln\left(x_k\right)\leq a\,\ln(c)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\right)\,\ln(a)+\sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\,\ln\left(a_k\right)=a\,\ln\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\,\ln\left(a_k\right)\,.$$
Note that inequality above becomes an equality if and only if $$\frac{x_1}{a_1}=\frac{x_2}{a_2}=\ldots=\frac{x_n}{a_n}=\frac{c}{a}\,,$$
or equivalently,
$$\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right)=\left(\frac{c\,a_1}{a},\frac{c\,a_2}{a},\ldots,\frac{c\,a_n}{a}\right)\,.$$
This shows that $$p^*= a\,\ln\left(\frac{c}{a}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\,\ln\left(a_k\right)\,.$$