# Maximizing the weighted sum of log likelihood function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization, convex-optimization, information-theory

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ is a iid random binary vector over the sample space $\Omega$ such that $\mathbf{X} \sim Bernoulli(\bar{\mathbf{p}})$. As a matter of notation, suppose $f(\cdot;\bar{\mathbf{p}})$ is the joint probability mass function (pmf) of $\mathbf{X}$, and $f(X_i;p_i)$ is the marginal pmf for the $i^{th}$ random variable for $i=1,2,\dots,N$. By definition, such a joint pmf is continuous and twice differentiable with respect to all its parameters.

Further, suppose, $\Xi \subset \Omega$. Thus,

$$
\sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \mathbf{\Xi}} f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}}) < 1 \quad \& \quad  f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}}) >0, \quad \forall \mathbf{X} \in \Xi\tag{0}\label{eq0}.
$$

I would like to maximize the following function:

$$
\max_{\mathbf{p}}\sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi}f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}}) \ln f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}) \tag{1}\label{eq1}, 
$$

where $\bar{\mathbf{p}}$ is the known parameter vector of $f(\cdot;\bar{\mathbf{p}})$, but $\mathbf{p}$ is unknown and needs to be optimized.

**My whole purpose in doing so, is to show that,**

$$
\sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}^*) \geq \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})\tag{2}\label{eq2},
$$

where, $\mathbf{p}^*$ is the maximizer of Eq \eqref{eq1}.

**This is what I tried:**

The first order condition for $p_i\in \mathbf{p}$ ($p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of the vector $\mathbf{p}$):

$$[p_i]: \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} \frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p})} f'(\mathbf{X};p_i) = \dots = \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} \frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p})} f'(\mathbf{X};p_j) = 0, \quad \forall p_i,p_j \in \mathbf{p} \tag{2a}\label{eqfoc}.$$

Because of the iid assumption in the beginning $f'(\mathbf{X};p_i) = f'(X_i;p_i) \frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}) }{f(X_i;p_i)}$, it follows that:

$$[p_i]: \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} \frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(X_i;p_i)} f'(X_i;p_i) = \dots = \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} \frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(X_j;p_j)} f'(X_i;p_j) = 0, \quad \forall p_i,p_j \in \mathbf{p}:i \neq j. \tag{2b}\label{eqfocb}$$

which implies that,

$$ \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} f'(X_i;p_i) = 0, \quad \forall p_i \in \mathbf{p} \tag{3}\label{eq3},$$

and

$$\frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p})} = \lambda (\text{some constant}), \quad \forall \mathbf{X} \in \Xi \tag{4}\label{eq4}.$$

Note that, Eq.\eqref{eq3} holds because of the following:

1. $\sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Omega} f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}) = 1 \implies \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Omega} f'(\mathbf{X};p_i) = 0, \forall p_i \in \mathbf{p}.$;
2. We assumed $\Xi \subset \Omega$, over which $f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})>0$ by Eq\eqref{eq0}.
3. $\frac{ f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}})}{ f(X_i;p_i)}>0$ by definition, and given, we have maximization problem and freedom to set each $p_i \in \mathbf{p}$, $f(X_i;p_i)>0, \forall X_i \in \mathbf{X} \in \Xi$ is not a constraint but an implication of the maximization.
4. Given $f(X_i;p_i)>0, \forall X_i \in \mathbf{X} \in \Xi$, then, $\sum_{X_i} f(X_i;p_i) = 1, \forall X_i \in \mathbf{X} \in \Xi$ which implies Eq\eqref{eq3}. Otherwise, it would mean that $\Xi \not\subset \omega$.

In turn, it implies that Eq\eqref{eq2}, because Eq\eqref{eq3} is actually, the first order condition for

$$\max_p \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}) = \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi}f(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{p}^*) \geq \sum_{\mathbf{X} \in \Xi} f(\mathbf{X};\bar{\mathbf{p}}). $$

**My questions:**

- Is my intuition correct? Is there any mistake?;
- I am a bit suspicious about Eq\eqref{eq3} and Eq\eqref{eq4}. I suspect there should be additional conditions there to get the latter. Could you help me with those conditions if there needs to be some?;
- Do you think it is possible to have Eq\eqref{eqfoc} true but not Eq\eqref{eq3} and Eq\eqref{eq4}?
- What I received is very similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998812/1036335). Thus, I believe the intuition is correct with some constraints on the pmfs missing though.

Comment: I suppose $X$ is not "iid", but rather has independent and unidentically distributed entries, or did I miss something?

Comment: Each element is iid, but if you compare two different elements they are independent but not identical. I mean the first element of the random vector is iid with respect to itself. But if you compare two different elements of the vector then they are most likely independent but not identical. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm super confused too. What does "first element is iid" mean? It's an element, you need at least two things to say that they are iid, right? Also what do you mean by "most likely independent"? Your notation suggests that $X \in \{0,1\}^n$ for some $n$, such that $ X_i \sim \mathrm{Bern}(\bar p_i)$ for each $i$, and all the $X_i$s are mutually independent. Is that correct? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, this is exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write the independent Bernoulli law as $f(x;p) = \prod_i p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{1-x_i},$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. I'll write $q$ instead of $\bar p$ to avoid having to type \bar repeatedly (and also I'll forego all the bolding in the question).

Let me denote $$ J(p;q,\Xi) := \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \log f(x;p).$$ We're interested in the program $$ J(q;\Xi) := \max_{p \in [0,1]^n} J(p;q,\Xi). $$

There are two slightly different ways to approach this. First if you want to directly take derivatives, then note that you'd need to introduce Lagrange multipliers to deal with the constraints on the entries of $p$, and use their complementary slackness to deal with things. More or less, this will devolve into the following condition, for each $i$. Consider the function $$ U(p_i;q,\Xi) := \sum_{x \in \Xi} \frac{ f(x;q)}{ p_i^{x_i} (1-p_i)^{1-x_i}} (2x_i - 1). $$ If $U(p_i;q,\Xi)$ has a root in $(0,1),$ then the optimal value of $p_i$ is that root. If it does not, then the optimal value is either  $0$ or $1$, depending on if $U \le 0$ or $\ge 0$ on $[0,1]$. The form of $U$ comes from exploiting the independence structure embedded in $f$.

---

But, we can exploit this independence structure from the get go. Notice that $$ J(p;q,\Xi) = \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \sum_i \varphi(x_i; p_i) = \sum_i J_i(p_i;q,\Xi),$$ where \begin{align} \varphi(x_i;p_i) &= x_i \log p_i + (1-x_i) \log (1-p_i)\\ J_i(p_i;q,\Xi) &= \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \varphi(x_i;p_i). \end{align}

An immediate observation is that the problem is completely decoupled over the $p_i$s, so we might as well understand just a single such problem. Let me further denote $F(\Xi;q) = \sum_{z \in \Xi} f(z;q),$ and the conditional law $f_\Xi(x;q) = f(x;q) \mathbf{1}\{x \in \Xi\}/F(\Xi;q)$. Then multiplying and divding by $F(\Xi;q),$ we have $$ \frac{J_i(p_i;q,\Xi)}{F(\Xi;q)} = \sum_{x} f_\Xi(x;q) (x_i \log p_i + (1-x_i) \log (1-p_i)) \\ = \mu_i(q,\Xi) \log p_i + (1-\mu_i(q;\Xi)) \log(1-p_i), $$ where $$ \mu_i(q;\Xi)  := \mathbb{E}_{X \sim q}[X_i|X \in \Xi].$$ Obviously $\mu_i \in [0,1]$. But note that this is just a (negative) cross entropy between binary laws with parameters $\mu_i(q;\Xi)$ and $p_i,$ so the maximiser is precisely $p_i = \mu_i(q;\Xi),$ and the optimal value is $$ -F(\Xi;q) \cdot \sum h_2(\mu_i(q;\Xi)),$$ where $h_2$ is the binary entropy function $h_2(z) = -z \log z - (1-z) \log(1-z)$.

Comment: I will have a closer look at your answer tomorrow. My question is whether we can extend this result to any pdf and to any pmf? Thanks.

Comment: I think in general things won't be so clean. The one gap I see in your argument  from the question regarding this is that when you set the $p_i$ derivatives to $0$, you're not accounting for the constraints on the $p_i$ (i.e., $0 \le p_i \le 1$). In general, your parameters _will_ live in some constrained set, and you'll have to introduce appropriate Lagrange multipliers to deal with these. Besides that, assuming convexity w.r.t. parameters, I see no problem with proceeding as you did (although how easy it is to figure things out in closed form is a different issue).

Comment: Note that because of this issue, your condition $(3)$ can possibly fail: if the optimal solution saturates some constraints, then the derivative need not be zero at the optimum.

Comment: Also, of course, note that even in the above, it is not true that $f(x;q)/f(x;p)$ is a constant: suppose $\Xi$ contains two points of the form $a = (0, x_{2:n})$ and $b = (1, x_{2:n})$. Then at the optimum, $f(a;q)/f(a;p) * f(b;p)/f(b;q) = (1-q_1)/q_1 \cdot \mu_1(q;\Xi)/(1-\mu_1(q;\Xi)),$ and you should be able to find $\Xi, q$ where this is not $1$.

Comment: I will get back to you tomorrow. Overall, it seems clearer. Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I understood your solution and very thankful for this. But how can we reach to the solution that: $\sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \leq \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;p^*)$?

Comment: I must have missed this comment, sorry. I added an answer to the new question you asked.