# Minimizing cross entropy between reference and target distributions over a restricted domain.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization, convex-analysis, information-theory

My question is related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728893/maximizing-the-weighted-sum-of-log-likelihood-function/4732881?noredirect=1#comment10033913_4732881). Suppose I am minimizing the cross entropy between target and reference distributions in a specific domain $\Xi$ as follows:

$$\max_{p \in [0,1]^n} \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \log f(x;p),$$

where $f(x;q) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i;q_i)$ is the joint Bernoulli law. The optimal solution is $p_i = E_{X \sim q} [X_i|X \in \Xi]$ shown in the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728893/maximizing-the-weighted-sum-of-log-likelihood-function/4732881?noredirect=1#comment10033913_4732881). I would like to show that, the total probability mass located on $x \in \Xi$ by the optimal reference distribution $f(x;p^{*})$ will be greater than or equal to the total probability mass located on $x \in \Xi$ domain by the target distribution $f(x;q)$. Mathematically, I need to show the following:

$$\sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;p^{*}) \geq \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q).$$

Intuitively, cross entropy minimization is equivalent to the maximum likelihood estimation, thus, the statement should hold true (at least under some conditions which I may overlook). Could you please help me to prove the above statement mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(\Xi;p) := \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;p),$ and $f(x;p|\Xi) := f(x;p)/F(\Xi;p)$, where the latter is the conditional law of $p$ given that $x$ lies in $\Xi$. You want to show that $F(\Xi;p^*) \ge F(\Xi;q)$. For this, first note that we can assume that for any $x \in \Xi, f(x;q) > 0,$ since otherwise this $x$ doesn't enter the optimisation anyway (equivalently, we can work with $\Xi' = \Xi - \{x : f(x;q) = 0\}$. Also note that $F(\Xi;p)> 0$ for any $p$ that optimises the objective, since otherwise $f(x;p) = 0$ for each $x$ and the optimal value would be $-\infty,$ but we know that $\sum f(x;q) \log f(x;q) > -\infty$.

Now, due to the optimality of $p^*,$ we know that \begin{align} \sum_\Xi f(x;q) \log \frac{f(x;p^*)}{f(x;q)} &\ge 0 \\ \iff \sum_{\Xi} f(x;q) \log \frac{f(x;p^*|\Xi) F(\Xi;p^*)}{f(x;q|\Xi) F(\Xi;q)} &\ge 0 \\
\iff  \sum_\Xi f(x;q|\Xi) \log \frac{F(\Xi;p^*)}{F(\Xi;q)} & \ge \sum_\Xi f(x;q|\Xi) \log \frac{f(x;q|\Xi)}{f(x;p^*|\Xi)}\\
\iff \log \frac{F(\Xi;p^*)}{F(\Xi;q)} &\ge D(f(\cdot;q|\Xi) \|f(\cdot; p^*|\Xi) \ge 0,\end{align} and the conclusion follows. Here the first step is Bayes' law, the second step uses properties of the $\log,$ and factors out $F(\Xi;q)$ from each $f(x;q)$, the final step is the standard nonnegativity of KL divergence (Gibbs' inequality).

Note that this doesn't use any specific property of $f,$ so the argument is completely generic.

Comment: @stochastocboy321 Does $\log \frac{F(\Xi;p^*)}{F(\Xi;q)} \ge 0 \implies \log \frac{F(\Xi;p^*)}{F(\Xi;q)} \ge D(f(\cdot;q|\Xi) \|f(\cdot; p^*|\Xi) \ge 0$?

Comment: @entropy I don't think I understand the question. If you're in the setting of the question (i.e., $q$ is the reference law, and $p^*$ you mean the output of the optimisation above), then note that the second relation is true (as the argument above shows), and in that case it is implied in the logical sense by any proposition, so the answer would be yes, but for trivial reasons.

Comment: If you're asking whether for any pair of laws $p,q$ and a set $\Xi$ it holds that $\log F(\Xi;p)/F(\Xi;q) \ge 0 \implies  \log F(\Xi;p)/F(\Xi;q) \ge D( \cdot)$, this is not true. For instance, take $\Xi$ to be the whole set, and $p,q$ to be different laws. Then $F(\Xi;p) = F(\Xi;q) = 1,$ so the log of the ratio is exactly $0$, but the KL divergence is positive (of course $D \ge 0$ always holds).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw $iff$ and I thought the two guys in the final line of your proof imply each other.  What did you mean by $iff$ in your proof?

Comment: Hey, could you help me with another related question please? 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4867612/1036335

Answer (score 0):

I have another very similar answer:

$$\max_{p} \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\log f(x;p) = \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\log f(x;p^*) \tag{1} \label{eq1}.$$

$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\log f(x;p^*) \geq \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\log f(x;q) \tag{2} \label{eq2}.$$

$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\big[\log f(x;p^*) - \log f(x;q) \big] \geq 0 \tag{3} \label{eq3}.$$

$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \log \frac{f(x;p^*)}{f(x;q)} \geq 0 \tag{4} \label{eq4}.$$

Assuming $f(x; p^*)>0$ and $f(x;q)>0$ over $\Xi$, then, it implies that,

$$ \implies \log \frac{f(x; p^*)}{f(x; q)} \leq \frac{f(x; p^*)}{f(x; q)} - 1, \forall x \in \Xi \tag{5} \label{eq5}.$$

Plugging \eqref{eq5} into \eqref{eq4} holds:
$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q)\big[\frac{f(x; p^*)}{f(x; q)} - 1\big] \geq 0$$

$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x; p^*) - \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \geq 0$$

$$\iff \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;p^*) \geq \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Can you think of the conditions where the inequality becomes strict?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 can we continue discussion on this topic? I put another related question for which I am searching for an answer desperately.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760420/maximizing-the-likelihood-over-the-truncated-support-always-leads-to-strictly-gr