# Inequality related to cross-enropy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, mutual-information

Suppose, $S: x \mapsto \mathbb{R}^1$ and $f(\cdot;p)$ is some parametric family of pdfs. Moreover,  $\sum_{x}1 \{S(X) \geq \gamma \} f(x;u)\log f(x;v) \geq \sum_{x}1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\}f(x;u)\log f(x;u)$. It implies that,
$$\sum_{x}1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\}f(x;v)\log f(x;v) \geq \sum_{x}1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\}f(x;v)\log f(x;u).$$
Based on the last equation, I would like to prove that, for any $f(x;k)$:
$$\sum_{x} 1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\} f(x;u) \log f(x;k) \leq \sum_{x} 1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\} f(x;u) \log f(x;v), $$
The following inequality
$$\sum_{x} 1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\}f(x;v)  \log f(x;v) \geq \sum_{x} 1\{S(X)\geq \gamma\} f(x;v) \log f(x;k) ,$$
Holds.

Comment: Define $S(x)$ explicitly please. The question should be self contained

Comment: @kodlu I edited the question upon your request.